# Drop columns in pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume that I have the following dataframe:

```
+---+---------+------+------+------+
|   | summary | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 0 | count   | 10   | 10   | 10   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 1 | mean    | 4    | 5    | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 2 | stddev  | 3    | 3    | 3    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 3 | min     | 0    | -1   | 5    |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
| 4 | max     | 100  | 56   | 47   |
+---+---------+------+------+------+
```

How can I  keep only the columns where  `count > 5`, `mean>4` and `min>0` including the column `summary` as well?

The desired output is:

```
+---+---------+------+
|   | summary | col3 |
+---+---------+------+
| 0 | count   | 10   |
+---+---------+------+
| 1 | mean    | 5    |
+---+---------+------+
| 2 | stddev  | 3    |
+---+---------+------+
| 3 | min     | 5    |
+---+---------+------+
| 4 | max     | 47   | 
+---+---------+------+
```

Comment: easiest to transform the dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
df2 = df.set_index('summary').T
m1 = df2['count'] > 5
m2 = df2['mean'] > 4
m3 = df2['min'] > 0
df2.loc[m1 & m2 & m3].T.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    summary col3
0   count   10
1   mean    5
2   stddev  3
3   min     5
4   max     47
```

Note: You can easily use the conditions directly in `.loc[]` , but when we have multiple conditions, it is best to use separate mask variables (`m1`, `m2`, `m3`)

Answer (score 2):

`loc` with callable.

```
(df.set_index('summary').T
   .loc[lambda x: (x['count'] > 5) & (x['mean'] > 4) & (x['min'] > 0)]
   .T.reset_index())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
s=df.set_index('summary')
com=pd.Series([5,4,0],index=['count','mean','min'])
idx=s.loc[com.index].gt(com,axis=0).all().loc[lambda x : x].index
s[idx]
Out[142]: 
         col3
summary      
count      10
mean        5
stddev      3
min         5
max        47
```

Answer (score 1):

#### General thrashing about plus `query`

```
(
    df.set_index('summary')
      .rename(str.title).T
      .query('Count > 5 & Mean > 4 and Min > 0')
      .T.rename(str.lower)
      .reset_index()
)

  summary  col3
0   count    10
1    mean     5
2  stddev     3
3     min     5
4     max    47
```

---

#### Shenanigans

```
(
    df[['summary']].join(
        df.iloc[:, 1:].loc[:, df.iloc[[0, 1, 3], 1:].T.gt([5, 4, 0]).all(1)]
    )
)
  summary  col3
0   count    10
1    mean     5
2  stddev     3
3     min     5
4     max    47
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `summary` columns as the index and then do this:

`df.T.query("(count > 5) & (mean > 4) & (min > 0)").T`

Comment: This does not work. `count` is not a column. :( Did you actually run the code?

Comment: @harvpan It is clearly stated that 'Set the summary column as the index', then transpose leads to `count` being a column

Comment: This is not a full answer as it doesn't show the relevant steps.  Further, count, mean and min are key words in the query syntax so it simply doesn't work with as described.

Comment: @MichaelD. I am expecting the OP to be able to set the summary column as an index. But the solution does work. Here is more complete answer that I've verified to work. Column names take precedence over methods.


`df = pd.DataFrame([['count', 10, 10, 10], ['mean', 4, 5, 5], ['stdev', 3, 3, 3], ['min', 0, -1, 5], ['max', 100, 56, 47]])`
`df.columns = ['summary', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']`
`df.set_index('summary').T.query("(count > 5) & (mean>4) & (min>0)").T`